# What is the recommended maximum size of an e-mail?

Tags: email, email-attachments

Max e-mail sizes vary wildly from server to server. Gmail has a cap at 25MB, some ISPs still cap at 10MB or even 5MB, and Exchange servers can be configured to however the individual company wants.

With all that in mind, is there a good recommendation for what the maximum size of a mail should be?

I would like to show my users a "people may not get this e-mail" warning, but I am not sure as to the threshold. Is 10MB still the magic number?